# can I use textblob for classification besides sentimental analysis?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, nltk, textblob, text-processing

I want to extract questions from question paper.I'm labeling each 
question as q and other sentences as i in dataset.

e.g.

```
Why is this sector becoming important in India,q
Describe any five public facilities needed for the development of a country,q
CBSE 10th English 2017 Unsolved Paper,i
THE MARKS ARE MENTIONED ON EACH QUESTION,i
```

Is it suitable to use textblob naivebayes classifier for this or should I use sklearn with nltk?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Comment: I'm not getting how to use basic nltk for extracting question.

Comment: Have you walkthrough all the code in the kaggle kernel? Also have you read the http://www.nltk.org/book/?

Comment: yes,still i'm not getting how to use nltk

Comment: Are you sure you went through the book? And the kaggle kernel? The kaggle kernel teaches you exactly how to build a classifier using sklearn and nltk for almost any classification task.

Comment: thanks for the links.It was helpful.Can you suggest something for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238091/is-it-correct-to-use-pos-tag-as-feature-in-questions-identification